# Binding a WPF ComboBox to a different ItemsSource within a ListBox DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, combobox, listbox, datatemplate, data-binding

I have a ListBox that contains a textbox and a combobox in its datatemplate:

```
<ListBox Height="147" Margin="158,29,170,0" Name="PitcherListBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding SomeCollectionOfObjects}" Background="Black">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding LocalArrayOfIntsProperty}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

I want to bind the listbox to a collection of objects (which I've done successfully), but I want the combobox in the above datatemplate to have its itemssource set to a local property on the window (array of ints).  I still want the combobox to have a two-way bind between its selected item and a property on the collection of objects...

I have the following in code:
PitcherListBox.DataContext = this;

Basically in the end, I want the combobox within the listbox to have a different itemssource than the listbox itself. I can't seem to figure out how to change the ComboBox's ItemsSource in XAML.  Can someone provide me some feedback? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding LocalArrayOfIntsProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type YourWindowTypeHere}}}" />
```

Note that you need to replace `YourWindowTypeHere` with the type of the Window containing the `LocalArrayOfIntsProperty`! Also remember that you will need to define an xml namespace for that type!

Comment: I created a namespace "xmlns:Local="clr-namespace:MyApp" and used the line provided below, using this for the type: AncestorType={x:Type Local:DetailsWindow} and I get an error: Ancestor type must be specified for relative source in FindAncestor mode

Comment: Nevermind, I just had to build and the error went away. Thanks so much for your help...

Comment: Yeah, this is a bug in VS2008 (do not know about VS2010). As you said, it typically disappears after re-building. BTW: If my answer was helpful, you should mark it as accepted by clicking on the checkmark besides my answer.