# Binding ComboBox in ListBox

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, combobox, listbox

I cant figure this one out.  If I just have the combo-box by itself not embedded in a list box it will populate and selected the values I need.

The XAML

```
<ComboBox Name="comboBox1" 
          Height="23" 
          DataContext="{Binding Combox}" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Comboxes}" 
          DisplayMemberPath="PV" 
          SelectedValuePath="PK"                  
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
          VerticalAlignment="Top" 
          Width="120" />
```

The Code Behind

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataAttribute d = new DataAttribute(2, "blue");

        Combox c = new Combox();

        c.SelectedItem = d;
        c.Comboxes.Add(new DataAttribute(1, "red"));

        c.Comboxes.Add(new DataAttribute(3, "Black"));
        c.Comboxes.Add(c.SelectedItem);

        comboBox1.DataContext = c;
    }
```

Class for holding data

```
public class Combox: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Combox()
    {
        Comboxes = new List<DataAttribute>();            
    }

    private DataAttribute _selectedItem;// = new DataAttribute(-1, "NA");

    public List<DataAttribute> Comboxes { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public DataAttribute SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _selectedItem; }
        set
        {
            if (_selectedItem == value) return;
            _selectedItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedValue");
        }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }        
}

public class DataAttribute
{
    public DataAttribute() { }

    public DataAttribute(int pk, string pv)
    {
        PK = pk;
        PV = pv;
    }

    public int PK { get; set; }
    public string PV { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return PV;
    }
}
```

All that works fine, but as soon as I try to create a list of com boxes in the listbox nothing.  I can see the combo but no data.  How on earth to you bind to it is XAML?

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        List<Combox> com = new List<Combox>();
        DataAttribute d = new DataAttribute(2, "blue");

        Combox c = new Combox();

        c.SelectedItem = d;
        c.Comboxes.Add(new DataAttribute(1, "red"));

        c.Comboxes.Add(new DataAttribute(3, "Black"));
        c.Comboxes.Add(c.SelectedItem);

        com.Add(c);

        lstTest.ItemSource = com;
    }
```

As here is the XAML with a listbox.  It no longer binds...

```
    <ListBox Name="lstTest" ItemsSource="{Binding}">        
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ComboBox Name="comboBox1" 
                      DataContext="{Binding Combox}" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Comboxes}" 
                      DisplayMemberPath="PV" 
                      SelectedValuePath="PK"                  
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
                      VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                      Width="120" />        
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>            
    </ListBox>
```

I am stumped as it was hard enough trying to figure out how to just get the selected object to appear without the list-box...

Comment: Maybe this link will be useful. I did that and it works.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695954/binding-a-wpf-combobox-to-a-different-itemssource-within-a-listbox-datatemplate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the items of an `ItemsControl` the `DataContext` is the currectly templated item, if you want to get to a list that is to be used as the `ItemsSource` for the `ComboBoxes` you normally need to modify the bindings to use another source, e.g. [`RelativeSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.relativesource.aspx) or [`ElementName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.elementname.aspx). (This is the case for one list that is to be used for all `ComboBoxes`)

In this case, where the list seems to be part of the item, you should only need to remove the binding on the `DataContext` as the `DataContext` is already the item (an instance of `Combox`).